# Hyperref Label Appearing in PDF Viewer's Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, viewers

I'm having a problem with hyperref and having the labels for my sections appearing in my PDF viewer's table of contents. The document itself looks fine, but (for example) when I look at the table of contents I'll see [1.1a] before the section title for the 1.1 problems and [1.1q] before the section title for the 1.1 answers. Basically I want the students to be able to click on the section title to jump to the answers for that section, and similarly for clicking on the section title in the answers section to jump back to the problems.

I've been Googling for a good amount of time, but I just don't know enough about hyperref to even formulate my search correctly. I did find something similar, but it had to do with the actual LaTeX table of contents, which I don't want in my document. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! MWE below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{\hyperref[1.1a]{\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System}}
\label{1.1q}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Find the distance between the points $P_1=(3,-4)$ and $P_2=(5,4)$.
    
    \item Find the midpoint of the line segment joining the points $P_1=(3,-4)$ and $P_2=(5,4)$.
\end{enumerate}

\newpage

\subsubsection{\hyperref[1.1q]{\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System}}
\label{1.1a}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\text{Distance} = 2\sqrt{17}$
    
    \item Midpoint: $(4,0)$
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the optional argument of `\subsubsection`: `\subsubsection[\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System]{\hyperref[1.1a]{\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System}}`. The optional argument (for `article`, `book` etc but not `memoir` which has 2 optional arguments) is the one that goes in the TOC and the PDF bookmarks are based on the TOC. Does this fix your issue in your main document?

Comment: If you need a purely `hyperref` solution then hopefully someone can answer as I do not have much intricate knowledge of `hyperref`!

Comment: @JamesT Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Using the optional arguments to `\subsubsection` means that the TOC (and hence bookmarks) can have whatever text you desire in and removes the hyperrlink:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection[\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System]{\hyperref[1.1a]{\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System}}
\label{1.1q}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Find the distance between the points $P_1=(3,-4)$ and $P_2=(5,4)$.
    
    \item Find the midpoint of the line segment joining the points $P_1=(3,-4)$ and $P_2=(5,4)$.
\end{enumerate}

\newpage

\subsubsection[{\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System}]{\hyperref[1.1q]{\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System}}
\label{1.1a}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\text{Distance} = 2\sqrt{17}$
    
    \item Midpoint: $(4,0)$
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

---

You could also create a command that attaches onto `\subsubsection` along the form of:

```
\newcommand\mysubsubsection[2]{\subsubsection[#1]{\hyperref[#2]{#1}}}
```

that you can then call with:

```
\mysubsubsection{\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System}{1.1a}
```

to remove too much hassle in having to have long `\subsubsection` commands.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newcommand\mysubsubsection[2]{\subsubsection[#1]{\hyperref[#2]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\mysubsubsection{\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System}{1.1a}
\label{1.1q}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Find the distance between the points $P_1=(3,-4)$ and $P_2=(5,4)$.
    
    \item Find the midpoint of the line segment joining the points $P_1=(3,-4)$ and $P_2=(5,4)$.
\end{enumerate}

\newpage

\mysubsubsection{\S 1.1 Real Numbers and the Rectangular Coordinate System}{1.1q}
\label{1.1a}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\text{Distance} = 2\sqrt{17}$
    
    \item Midpoint: $(4,0)$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!